# React - Why would a component re-render if props nor state changed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a weird scenario where a component is rendering twice, even though between those two renderings, the props aren't changing (and state is null since it has no state). I did a deep comparison of the props before and after (`this.props` vs `nextProps` argument in `shouldComponentUpdate`), and they're entirely equal. I thought it was only props and state that caused `render` to fire?

Comment: how does the component rendered through? does it rendered through clicks? if through clicks, you might want to double check for bubble events. usually this is the cause.

Comment: No, this is just upon page load and nothing else.

Comment: BTW, `shouldComponentUpdate` apparently only gets fired if props or state change. If I click into a text field and that gets focus, `render` does fire off, but `shouldComponentUpdate` does not.

Comment: As soon as the React Component is mounted `render` will trigger on lots of things no matter if state or props has changed therefore you shortcircuit the re-render with the `shouldComponentUpdate`, this will also always be fired off before the render no matter if state or props has changed.

Comment: @limelights That's a cyclical statement.. "`render` will be triggered on all subsequent renders." `render` doesn't just keep firing off arbitrarily. There are set conditions under which `render` is invoked. What are they?

Comment: The conditions would be either a new call to a life cycle method or a call to any parent components `this.setState` or a `this.setState` within your component itself. Can you post some code?